# How to get full path to executed file?

Tags: php, filepath

I'm trying to get the full path of the current executed file within PHP.

`realpath()` returns the path *without* the script filename.
`pathinfo()` you cannot use without passing it the whole path to break down.
`__FILE__` gets the path of the calling file (ie; where the `__FILE__` constant was called), which may be inside an `included file`; which I don't want.

The `$_SERVER` variables `REQUEST_URI`, `SCRIPT_NAME` & `PHP_SELF` don't returns the full path.

The most promising is the `$_SERVER` variable `SCRIPT_FILENAME` apart from the caveat..

> If a script is executed with the CLI, as a relative path, such as file.php or ../file.php, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] will contain the relative path specified by the user.

I want exactly what `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` returns such as `/home/site/public_html/index.php`, but just not 100% sure if using that is safe to use in all instances?

Is the latter the best method to use? Apart from the CLI, will it always return the correct path for normal web requests?

Comment: may b this is you want `dirname(__FILE__)."/curruntFile.php"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$a = get_included_files();
echo $a[0];
```

Quote from [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) documentation:

> The script originally called is considered an "included file," so it
>   will be listed together with the files referenced by include and
>   family.

## Test

```
<!-- main.php -->
<?php include "middle.php"; ?>

<!-- middle.php -->
<?php include "inner.php"; ?>

<!-- inner.php -->
<?php var_dump(__FILE__, $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], get_included_files()); ?>
```

## Output

```
string(21) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inner.php"
string(9) "/main.php"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\main.php" <-- this is what you are looking for
  [1]=>
  string(22) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\middle.php"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inner.php"
}
```

Comment: Nice! That seemed to do it! :)

Comment: An interesting difference between this and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is this will return the 100% true path with backslashes on Windows systems and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will return the path with forward slashes. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the current file you can retrieve it by using the global instance

```
__FILE__
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php for more info
If you would like to retrieve the directory where the file is located

```
// PHP < 5.3 
dirname(__FILE__);

// PHP > 5.3 
__DIR__
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

EDIT:
To retrieve the current **executing script**, you can get

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

This will return the filename of the exectued file. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for more info.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I already explained I cannot use `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__);` or if you are on php > 5.3 just `__DIR__;`

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: That gives me the path of the file that that code was placed in, not the path of the executed file such as `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` does.